# FreeNAS – Using External HDD

Tags: laptop, external-hard-drive, freenas

My Western Digital NAS seems to have gone up in smoke, so I was thinking of having a go with FreeNAS and a laptop I have have lying around.

Just got a couple of questions first. 
The laptop has only a 300 GB hard drive so can I connect up and external HDD via to increase the storage of FreeNAS. I have a couple of 500 GB external drives that I would like to use.

Also I have a backup of all the data that was on the Western Digital NAS before it failed. How do I go about copying this data onto the laptop/FreeNAS? Is this a simple process? As this is the only backup I have and it has all my music on it, I really don't want to mess it up and end up somehow losing it.

Comment: [SF] is for Professional System Administrator (et al) only. Please see [SU] or [Unix.SE] for questions about non-professional use.

Answer (score 0):

Using a laptop doesn't seem terribly reliable. Connecting external drives is just as you'd expect. Restoring from backup would depend on how you connect to the FreeNAS machine. I would recommend setting up SMB/CIFS/Samba, then mapping a network drive on your "normal" computer. Restoring from backup shouldn't hurt the original backup, just don't do anything dumb.